# Display a custom sign_in form anywhere in the rails app but for 2 devise models signing through one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models and I wish to have a form in my nav bar where I have the email field, password and submit button. Something similar to what devise sign in already provides with. But the thing is, I have two devise models. If I had only one model, according to this guide https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

I could just paste the below code in my helper and I will be fine, but what if I have two models? How can I have the users sign through one form?

```
def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is it possible that email address record for some user duplicates in both models?

Comment: nope. They are all unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
@var1 = Model1.find_by_email(params[:email])
@var2 = Model2.find_by_email(params[:email]) 
sign_in @var1 || @var2
```

small explain
find_by_attr will return nil if nothing was found
and then you with logical or can sign_in the existing user. However you should add something like to avoid `sign_in nil` if no record was found at all

```
sign_in(@var1 || @var2) if @var1 || @var2
```

Comment: Where does it go but? And what should my forms for signing should be posting?

Comment: this should go into controller that serves your sign_in, for ex SessionsController

Comment: well i tried overriding the devise controller but didnt work. As I was running into a `nil` resource. You can look it up here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: overriding sessions controller is a little different topic. The code above should work for your purpose, and have to be in controller that responsible for new session

Comment: Hi there, I have another question. i am generating my sign in form using `<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` but apparently i need to define `resource, resource name` in the application helper first. In that case, how can i have it for both the models? Because not having the form setup that way (through the code mentioned above in this comment) gives an error (as you can guess).

Comment: FYI, the error I get is `undefined local variable or method `resource'`. I was going to try your method but cant past the bug in order to try what you said above.

Comment: you dont have to pass anything for your sign in url, you will manage all info in controller without any arguments from path, only params

Answer (score -1):

Create a wrapper model for the sign_in form and use logic in your login action to decide which of your two user models to use.

It's not really a wrapper, but I can't think of the right word.

Comment: I am not sure, I understad you. If its not a wrapper what is it?

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly wrap your models. It just masks them. Anyway, that's technicalities.

Create a new model to use for your sign_in form. Then, when the login button is clicked, initialize the correct user model.

Comment: yep thats what i am asking for here, i guess :).

Comment: what do you mean by "thats what i am asking for here"? Did I answer your question?

Comment: ah, i see you just updated the question. Well, I mean what kind of logic should I be using?

Comment: That requires me to do research. You'll have to wait for me to go Google or for someone else to show up. I don't do a lot of rails dev, so I'm going off of concepts here. You'd need to post your two user models and I'd need to go find out what catches the Devise login action.

Comment: It looks like you can't catch the login action for Devise, but what you can do is allow login with the wrapper model and then create your own user_signed_in? helper methods (with different names unless you can override Devise's). The helper methods would check the rest of your state to see which of your two models you need to use.